# Hide list view to a group of users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have 2 different views in a SharePoint list. 
I want one view only for the managers and another for the users. Groups of managers and users are already done, I have seen a couple of Solutions around the Network but they don´t really work to me... I have SharePoint 2013 and work with SharePoint Designer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more which approaches you have gone through already, and *why* they didn't work for you, so an already tried approach won't be suggested again as an answer.

Comment: One Solution was creating a view, copying this view in the documents library and then deleting it from the views in the list, so the Managers can access to the view directly from the library (Users have no Access to the documents library), but even though I deleted the view it still appears in the list (so basically doesn´t work). Then I found this one http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/hide-list-views-certain-users-sharepoint/ but apparently is basically an Add-On

Comment: Is the same process for hiding views with target audience, possible in SharePoint Modern View experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need SharePoint Designer to achieve this functionality. You can simply set the "Target Audience" for your particular view.
Action Plan:

1. Open your List/Library and click on your respective View
2. From Site action icon, Click on Edit page
3. Select the webpart and click on Edit web part
4. Under Advanced section you will find Target audience
5. Put your respective SP groups and click OK
   and you are ready

[image: Screen 1][image: Screen 2]