# Hide list view to a group of users and Show some message to the othe users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am using Share point on premises. By using the instructions [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217909/hide-list-view-to-a-group-of-users), I am able to hide a list from group of users, but I am unable to hide this list view from my Home screen.

How can I add one "Access Restriction" message to the users who does not have access to the list? Is there a way to hide the link from the users for those specific user group?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a content editor web part to the bottom of the list view page and also specify a target audience.  Then enter in the message those users are supposed to see if they do not have access to the list view web part.

I don't know how your link is displaying, but if you are using the normal left hand navigation - those links can also have a target audience set.